# Can't set comma NSNumberFormater

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsnumberformatter

Help me please if you can.

I created formater for my text field and then in ViewController I am trying to set it:

```
OnlyNeddedNumbers *numbersOnly = [[OnlyNeddedNumbers alloc] init];
[self.betAmount setFormatter:numbersOnly];
```

but when I start the app I can't set dot or comma. The aim was allow user to set only double values into the NSTextField

```
@interface OnlyNeddedNumbers : NSNumberFormatter

@end


@implementation OnlyNeddedNumbers

- (BOOL)isPartialStringValid:(NSString*)partialString newEditingString:(NSString**)newString errorDescription:(NSString**)error
{

    if([partialString length] == 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    NSString *scanString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [partialString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""]];
    scanString = [scanString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];

    NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:scanString];

    if(!([scanner scanInt:0] && [scanner isAtEnd])) {
        NSBeep();
        return NO;
    } else if ([scanString isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        NSBeep();
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: I am using OS X. It is program for OS X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need special subclass. Your aim is

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setDecimalSeparator:@","];
[formatter setMinimum:@(-100000)];
[formatter setMaximum:@(100000)];
```

When you set minimum and maximum it will validate the value automatically. No other code required.

Remember 0.00 is also a valid double value.
You can also test for the value [object doubleValue] -> I would consider this as correct approach. If a user inserts text than it will be converted to double number 0.

[image]